# Google Meet permanent room

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, url, url-shortening, google-meet

When we start a meeting we get a meeting URL like `meet.google.com/xxx-yyyy-zzz`. Is there a way to get a customized and/or permanent meeting URL?

Even "customized" is an optional one, the requirement is to create a permanent room so that anyone can join that room without having the unique URL. This is very much useful when you have a recurrent meeting or a quick get-together. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- go to **https://bitly.com/**
- create a free account
- click on that orange button **CREATE**
- select **BITLINK**
- paste your meeting URL
- customize it as you wish (example: **`bit.ly/lets-meet-now`**)
- click on **SAVE** button

[image: 1]

Comment: That's an intriguing solution. Are there any prerequisites such as registered or paid accounts that are needed for such a customised link?

Comment: @Mokubai no need for a paid premium account on bitly to create a custom link. the free account is more than sufficient to handle it.

Comment: I have done perm  (or to be more precise, name-my-link) links on other services without an account.  But while .ly is a fun "adverb extension", it is also under control of the government of Libya.  You know, Muammar Khadafy, Benghazi, *that Lybia*.  The security implications of that are unnerving.

Comment: @Harper The root servers connect a user to the server that the website is hosted on. But those servers don't always physically exist in the countries their TLDs are assigned to. Sites with the .ly TLD have five root servers, but only two are based in Libya: The other two are located in Oregon, and one is in the Netherlands.


For a site like bit.ly with a .ly TLD, all five of the root servers would need to go down at the same time for access to the site to be restricted. It's nerdy, but integral to understanding why bit.ly kept chugging along when the Libyan government killed the Internet.

Comment: @Harper Even if all five of the root servers were somehow taken offline, users could still access the site through the alternative j.mp or bitly.com, a bit.ly spokesman said. Every bit.ly short URL also exists as a separate bitly.com page. Since the company's .com and .mp sites use alternate TLDs, they would be unaffected by the fact that .ly sites were down.

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER when I say "the security implications are unnerving", I don't mean the Libyan government *merely downing* .ly domains in a passive-aggressive pout.  The Libyan government has the authority to take control of all root servers, and that could seem innocuous at the time they do it.  Think sneakier...

Comment: Nowadays Google Meet links expire. Ref. https://apps.google.com/meet/

Answer (score 7):

Update

From https://apps.google.com/meet/

> A meeting link remains active until the meeting has ended. Meeting links for recurring meetings will stay active for as long as the event repeats.

Options

1. Create a recurring event in Google Calendar with no end-date.
2. Create a Room in Google Chat.
3. Create a class in Google Classroom. You should start the videocall from the link included in the class. Once the videocall is started a link to it could be shared but it will expire when the videocall ends.

---

Google Meet meetings URL are permanent. Just save it on a safe place.

Tip: Use Google Calendar to create a recurrent meeting.

NOTE: If you created a non-recurring event using Google Meet, you could use the same Google Meet meeting URL.

Comment: This solution does not work without needing a calendar entry, tried it.

Comment: The link no longer works after a while it seems google just 'deletes' the chat room on their side, unless it is in a calendar entry.  I let a link not being used for 2 months and it jsut no longer pointed to any existing chat rooms even if I was the one that hosted it could not even open it.

Comment: So only the first part of your tip seems to work, unfortuantely for me.  i have irregular meeting but i need to be able to keep the same  chat room once it is created for a specific group.  I'll have to dig a different tool i guess

Comment: @KilrathiSly You are right. Answer updated

Comment: @Rubén so to confirm, if you have the URL to the meeting room e.g. `meet.google.com/xxx-yyyy-zzz` this link will never expire? Even without a calendar entry?