# What is the duration of a Google Meet URL? (personal account)

Tags: google-workspace, google-meet

I have a personal Google account. I can create Google Meet rooms easily by clicking on the "Start a meeting" button:

[image]

The URLs created by clicking that button are like **`https://meet.google.com/xxx-yyyy-zzz`**. The problem is, it seems it is not possible to create a room with an arbitrary `xxx-yyyy-zzz` (see [this example](https://meet.google.com/wdi-naaq-gvc)).

[image]

So, I am guessing, in order to create a new room/URL for a meeting, you *need* to use the "Start a meeting" button.

The thing is, I would like to use the same URL/link for meetings with someone in the future (i.e.: I would like to bookmark it and reuse it anytime I want to talk to that person). I wonder if the link will still be valid then.

What is the duration of that link/URL? Do I need to revisit the URL from time to time in order to avoid expiration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Meet permanent room](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124398/google-meet-permanent-room)

Comment: @Rubén Not really, since it does not answer my question (I want to know the duration of a Google Meet link for non-recurring events).. :-)

Comment: Please share what happens with your >90 days rooms :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading answers from  [this question](https://support.google.com/meet/thread/32930317?hl=en) from Google Meet Help, as long as you regularly used the link, then the link continues to remain valid. **However, it expires after 90 days if not used** but there is always the possibility that
Google will change its policy so maybe make an entry in your diary beforehand to make sure it persists.

Comment: Thanks! Suggested edit: enphasize **expires after 90 days if not used** and maybe note that you can use the recurrent calendar event trick to avoid expiration. :-)

Comment: If it's really important don't rely on things that arent's supported by an official doc. Google could change it's mind in anytime without announcing it. The referred thread is locked, it's from 6 months ago and it's about a product with changing policies due to the COVID-19 contingency.

Comment: @Rubén You are 100% right about advice/suggestion/caution.